Python library sportsreference error: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
I am using google collab here with the sportsreference python library and pandas
The goal here is to collect NFL boxscores data from the past 25 years from sportsreference.com and return all the data nicely in a csv
Here is the library i am using below
!pip install sportsreference
Here is the code to get data for NFL regular season games
from sportsreference.nfl.boxscore import Boxscores
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Calculate the starting year (25 years ago from the current year)
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
start_year = current_year - 25

# Initialize an empty list to hold DataFrames for each season
all_games_stats = []

# Loop through each year from the start year to the current year
for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
    print(f"Fetching data for the {year} season...")
    try:
        # Fetch all games for the given season
        season_start = datetime.date(year, 9, 1)
        season_end = datetime.date(year + 1, 2, 28)  # February 28th of the following year

        # Debugging: Check start and end dates
        print(f"Start Date: {season_start}, End Date: {season_end}")

        # Fetch boxscores between the start and end dates
        season_games = Boxscores(season_start, season_end)
        
        # Check if any games were found for the season
        if season_games.games:
            print(f"Games found for the {year} season.")
            # Extract all game data
            for week in season_games.games:
                week_games = season_games.games[week]
                for game in week_games:
                    game_data = game['boxscore']
                    game_df = pd.DataFrame([game_data])
                    all_games_stats.append(game_df)
        else:
            print(f"No games found for the {year} season.")
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred for the {year} season: {e}")

# Check if we have any data before concatenating
if all_games_stats:
    # Concatenate all game DataFrames into a single DataFrame
    nfl_games_stats_df = pd.concat(all_games_stats, ignore_index=True)

    # Display the first few rows of the DataFrame
    print(nfl_games_stats_df.head())

    # Optionally, save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    nfl_games_stats_df.to_csv('nfl_games_stats_past_25_years.csv', index=False)
else:
    print("No data was collected. Please check your data fetching logic.")

And below is the error i get
Fetching data for the 1999 season...
Start Date: 1999-09-01, End Date: 2000-02-28
An error occurred for the 1999 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2000 season...
Start Date: 2000-09-01, End Date: 2001-02-28
An error occurred for the 2000 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2001 season...
Start Date: 2001-09-01, End Date: 2002-02-28
An error occurred for the 2001 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2002 season...
Start Date: 2002-09-01, End Date: 2003-02-28
An error occurred for the 2002 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2003 season...
Start Date: 2003-09-01, End Date: 2004-02-28
An error occurred for the 2003 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2004 season...
Start Date: 2004-09-01, End Date: 2005-02-28
An error occurred for the 2004 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2005 season...
Start Date: 2005-09-01, End Date: 2006-02-28
An error occurred for the 2005 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2006 season...
Start Date: 2006-09-01, End Date: 2007-02-28
An error occurred for the 2006 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2007 season...
Start Date: 2007-09-01, End Date: 2008-02-28
An error occurred for the 2007 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2008 season...
Start Date: 2008-09-01, End Date: 2009-02-28
An error occurred for the 2008 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2009 season...
Start Date: 2009-09-01, End Date: 2010-02-28
An error occurred for the 2009 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2010 season...
Start Date: 2010-09-01, End Date: 2011-02-28
An error occurred for the 2010 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2011 season...
Start Date: 2011-09-01, End Date: 2012-02-28
An error occurred for the 2011 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2012 season...
Start Date: 2012-09-01, End Date: 2013-02-28
An error occurred for the 2012 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2013 season...
Start Date: 2013-09-01, End Date: 2014-02-28
An error occurred for the 2013 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2014 season...
Start Date: 2014-09-01, End Date: 2015-02-28
An error occurred for the 2014 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2015 season...
Start Date: 2015-09-01, End Date: 2016-02-28
An error occurred for the 2015 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2016 season...
Start Date: 2016-09-01, End Date: 2017-02-28
An error occurred for the 2016 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2017 season...
Start Date: 2017-09-01, End Date: 2018-02-28
An error occurred for the 2017 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2018 season...
Start Date: 2018-09-01, End Date: 2019-02-28
An error occurred for the 2018 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2019 season...
Start Date: 2019-09-01, End Date: 2020-02-28
An error occurred for the 2019 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2020 season...
Start Date: 2020-09-01, End Date: 2021-02-28
An error occurred for the 2020 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2021 season...
Start Date: 2021-09-01, End Date: 2022-02-28
An error occurred for the 2021 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2022 season...
Start Date: 2022-09-01, End Date: 2023-02-28
An error occurred for the 2022 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2023 season...
Start Date: 2023-09-01, End Date: 2024-02-28
An error occurred for the 2023 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
Fetching data for the 2024 season...
Start Date: 2024-09-01, End Date: 2025-02-28
An error occurred for the 2024 season: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
No data was collected. Please check your data fetching logic.

Here is the error i get when i remove the try and except blocks
Fetching data for the 1999 season...
Start Date: 1999-09-01, End Date: 2000-02-28
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-083ec7867b08> in <cell line: 13>()
     22 
     23     # Fetch boxscores between the start and end dates
---> 24     season_games = Boxscores(season_start, season_end)
     25 
     26     # Check if any games were found for the season

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sportsreference/nfl/boxscore.py in _find_games(self, week, year, end_week)
   1627             timestamp = '%s-%s' % (week, year)
   1628             self._boxscores[timestamp] = boxscores
-> 1629             week += 1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'


Get rid of the try/except so you can show the full traceback of the error. I don't see any += in your code, so it must be happening in something you're calling.

that's because its within the sportsreference package in the boxscore.py file

@WarSaw - couple things. 1) the Boxscore takes in the parameters of week, year, and end_week. You are inpute dates. 2) the sportreference package is 4 years old and not been maintained. It's outdated. So even adjusting those parameters is not returning anything with the Pyquery that this package is using. You'll need to adjust the packages code, or just build out a html parser your self. My suggestion is build it out from scratch.

try the following -
In your code, fix this:
# Loop through each year from the start year to the current year
for year in range(start_year, current_year + 1):
    print(f"Fetching data for the {year} season...")
    try:
        # Fetch all games for the given season
        season_start = datetime.date(year, 9, 1)
        season_end = datetime.date(year + 1, 2, 28)  # February 28th of the following year

        # Debugging: Check start and end dates
        print(f"Start Date: {season_start}, End Date: {season_end}")

        # Fetch boxscores between the start and end dates
        season_games = Boxscores(week=1, year=year, end_week=18)  ## <--- CHANGE TO THIS
        
        # Check if any games were found for the season
        if season_games.games:
            print(f"Games found for the {year} season.")
            # Extract all game data
            for week in season_games.games:
                week_games = season_games.games[week]
                for game in week_games:
                    game_data = game['boxscore']
                    game_df = pd.DataFrame([game_data])
                    all_games_stats.append(game_df)
        else:
            print(f"No games found for the {year} season.")
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred for the {year} season: {e}")

Then find the boxscore.py file, add import requests at the top, and change this:
def _get_requested_page(self, url):
    """
    Get the requested page.

    Download the requested page given the created URL and return a PyQuery
    object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : string
        The URL containing the boxscores to find.

    Returns
    -------
    PyQuery object
        A PyQuery object containing the HTML contents of the requested
        page.
    """
    return pq(requests.get(url).content)  ## <--- CHANGE TO THIS

